# Dragonwar ELE G9 Mouse SCROLL not working in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

The middle mouse button and scroll doesn't work in Linux Mint 18.
Please Advise.
This perticular mouse has a driver which allows changing of profiles. The mouse and the driver worked in windows.
I've tried installing the driver in Wine but executable file doesn't run.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: some detail would be good eg; has this mouse worked on other OS's, did it just stop and so on.please take some time to read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It appears this mouse has windows support only, I tried it on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.2 and it doesn't work at all.

https://www.dragonwar.jp/product/item/43-G9+3200+DPI+LED+Macro+Gaming+Mouse#download